# Why is this URL invalid?

Tags: url, uri, encodeuricomponent

http://localhost/#/showinfo/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fapi%2Fobject%2F1%2Fcollection%2F1

I'm trying to pass a URL thats encoded with `encodeURIComponent` to another page. but it seems that the URL is invalid.

Comment: i think the issue is in #

Comment: @PedroMonteiro -interesting, why would # matter? Its a shame, I can't remove it this is a URL into an AngularJS app.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3

Comment: `#` means that the rest of the URL is the hash. Only the part to the left of the `#` is sent to the server.